# Autofill the columns from a lookup sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a google sheet which I want my colleague to fill the data manually to cross-check whether there is any difference in the system and the manual notes.

I have the data from the system in another sheet/another page. I want 1-2 columns to auto-populate when my colleague enters a value in a particular column.

Attached the image of the system data which I think of comparing(Lookup), SO my idea is to fill the category name & category ID when my colleague type the SKU in the sheet.

Can anyone help me with this or suggest me what to do? What all I have to do for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your picture is Sheet2 you can do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Sheet2!D:D, Sheet2!A:B}, {2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]